# Fake malware warning at startup (Lenovo EMC Storage Manager)

Tags: mac, malware

Every time I start up my Mac I have this warning popping out.

[image]
It basically says "Lenovo EMC Storage manager will damage your computer. You should move it to the bin".
I do so every time but it doesn't go away. At the next reboot/Startup it pops out again.
The Lenovo EMC storage Manager was a proper app from Lenovo which I use to manage my NAS. Since the app was quite buggy, I removed it long time ago. The pop out started bothering me after I updated to Catalina and I am now on MacOS Big Sur.

I have tried to search for files "Lenovo" but no luck. Any advice on how to find and remove such file forever? The app was removed long time ago.

Thanks

PS
Is there a way to identify this warning pop up information from the system logs? May be I can trace it back from there and remove the file.